# Not able to loop through Angular array?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, multidimensional-array

Im trying to loop through this array.

However, it doenst show me anything inside the `{{repeat.title}}`

Im looping through the array with the following HTML/Angular code:

```
<div class="column inline inline-4 center choice" ng-repeat="repeat in repeater.keuze_menu[0]">
    <span>{{repeat.title}}</span>
</div>
```

**Angular object**

```
$scope.repeater = [{
    "uitgelichte_afbeelding": false,
    "content_afbeelding": "http:\/\/hetplein.h2505194.stratoserver.net\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/05\/image2.jpg",
    "keuze_menu": [{
        "keuze_1": {
            "ID": 81,
            "id": 81,
            "title": "IJs",
            "filename": "Ijs-1.jpg",
            "url": "http:\/\/hetplein.h2505194.stratoserver.net\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/05\/Ijs-1.jpg",
            "alt": "",
            "author": "1",
            "description": "",
            "caption": "",
            "name": "ijs-2",
            "date": "2016-07-14 09:32:06",
            "modified": "2016-07-15 11:37:33",
            "mime_type": "image\/jpeg",
            "type": "image",
            "icon": "http:\/\/hetplein.h2505194.stratoserver.net\/wp-includes\/images\/media\/default.png",
            "width": 1440,
            "height": 956,
            "sizes": {
                "thumbnail": "http:\/\/hetplein.h2505194.stratoserver.net\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/05\/Ijs-1-150x150.jpg",
                "thumbnail-width": 150,
                "thumbnail-height": 150,
                "medium": "http:\/\/hetplein.h2505194.stratoserver.net\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/05\/Ijs-1-300x199.jpg",
                "medium-width": 300,
                "medium-height": 199,
                "medium_large": "http:\/\/hetplein.h2505194.stratoserver.net\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/05\/Ijs-1-768x510.jpg",
                "medium_large-width": 768,
                "medium_large-height": 510,
                "large": "http:\/\/hetplein.h2505194.stratoserver.net\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/05\/Ijs-1-1024x680.jpg",
                "large-width": 1024,
                "large-height": 680
            }
        }
    }]
}]
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: You want to loop over an object, not an array...

Answer (score 2):

You want to loop over the keys in an object that happen to be in the first index of an array. For that you want to use [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in repeater.keuze_menu[0]">
    <span>{{value.title}}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Here is the link: http://hetplein.h2505194.stratoserver.net/ might help

Answer (score 0):

With angular.forEach() https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach

```
angular.forEach(values, function(value, key) {
  this.push(key + ': ' + value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Finaly after trying everything i could think off, i found the solution.

```
<div class="column inline inline-4 center choice" ng-repeat="repeat in repeater">
    <div ng-repeat="value in repeat.keuze_menu[0]">
        <span>{{value.title}}</span>
        <img alt="" src=""/>
    </div>
</div>
```

I just had to call the repeater twice.